# Manually rotate image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing

I already save my image information in bitmap:

```
for(int j=0; j<tinggi; j++) {   
    for(int i=0; i<lebar; i++) {
        warna = pixels[j*lebar+i];
        alpha = (warna >>24) &0xff;
        red = (warna >>16) & 0xff;
        bmpR[i][j] = red;
        green = (warna >>8) &0xff;
        bmpG[i][j] = green;
        blue = blue = (warna ) &0xff;
        bmpB[i][j] = blue;
        }
    }
```

I try to rotate the image with this code:

```
for(int j=0;j<tinggi;j++) { 
    for(int i=0;i<lebar;i++) {
        double xr = (i*Math.cos(r))-(j*Math.sin(r));
        double yr = (i*Math.sin(r))+(j*Math.cos(r));
        int xro =  (int) Math.round(xr);
        int yro =  (int) Math.round(yr);
        rotationR [i+ xro][j+ yro] = (bmpR[i][j]);
        rotationG [i+ xro][j+ yro] = (bmpG[i][j]);
        rotationB [i+ xro][j+ yro] = (bmpB[i][j]);
        }
    }    

for(int j=0;j<tinggi;j++) { 
    for(int i=0;i<lebar;i++) {
        g.setColor(new Color(rotationR[i][j], rotationG[i][j], rotationB[i][j]));
        g.drawLine(i+lebar+100, j+450, i+lebar+100, j+450);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't output anything (While the translation and scaling is working).

[image]

What's wrong with my rotation code?

Comment: Check if the r for the rotation is supposed to be in radians or in degrees?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani I already declare it with Radians
double r =  Math.toRadians(30);

Comment: what the heck are you doing with this?? g.drawLine(i+lebar+100, j+450, i+lebar+100, j+450); - is this considered normal coordinates in your town?? just put down normal coordinates

Comment: @gpasch Lecturer thing dude....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a flaw in your logic:

you have to store the new location in a array instead of changing the array indice

```
Point[][] rotatedLocations = ...

for(int j=0;j<tinggi;j++) { 
    for(int i=0;i<lebar;i++) {
        double xr = (i*Math.cos(r))-(j*Math.sin(r));
        double yr = (i*Math.sin(r))+(j*Math.cos(r));
        int xro =  (int) Math.round(xr);
        int yro =  (int) Math.round(yr);
        rotatedLocations[i][j] = new Point(xr, yr);
    }
}
```

when you draw the pixel, draw them just on the associated location

```
for(int j=0;j<tinggi;j++) { 
    for(int i=0;i<lebar;i++) {

        //new (rotated) location for original x/y
        Point rotatedLocation = rotatedLocations[i][j];

        //color from the original
        g.setColor(new Color(original[i][j], original[i][j], original[i][j]));

        //but drawn on the new (rotated) location
        g.drawLine(rotatedLocation.x, rotatedLocation.y, rotatedLocation.x, rotatedLocation.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: It says i can't sum xr with xro inside the point because xr is double.

Comment: my mistake, just use `xr` instead (i'll adjust my answer)

Comment: There's an error to in: Point rotatedLocation = rotatedLocations[i][j]; Because it's already declared on the top

Comment: And i don't think this will work: g.drawLine(rotatedLocation.x, rotatedLocation.y, rotatedLocation.x, rotatedLocation.y);

Because i don't have x and y

Comment: `rotatedLocation.x` and `y` are properties of the `Point`... they are already set in `rotatedLocations[i][j] = new Point(xr, yr);`

Comment: 2 errors: variable rotatedLocation already declared in method <method name>
 
  and array required, but point found.

Comment: then rename the variable `Point[][] rotatedLocations` - i cannot see what variables you have already declared, since you posted snippets...

Comment: have a close look on `rotatedLocations` and `rotatedLocation` (one has an 's' in the ending)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123502/discussion-between-martin-frank-and-rainzo78).

Comment: I don't understand when you use Original[j] in g.Setcolor. I don't have that variable so i change that with my RGB Bitmap.